# What is the consistency of the Finish Line Dry Teflon?

Tags: chain, lubricant

I am doing some test for my home purposes of different lubes, and I was quite surprised I have three bottles of Finish Line Dry Teflon with two different forms. I shook all before applying and the bottle I have from the old times have foam like form (it liquefies after a while), but in two new bottles I have a water-like consistency (or even with less viscosity), no foam for sure.

I checked [Finish Line video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbi6JO_XGrk), from the shots presented it looks to my eye like light foam there. The video is from 2013. So my question is -- should be foam-like or water-like? Did FL change the formula (the bottles except for DuPont labels look identical)? Or does the form change in time, meaning fresh lube is water-like and it becomes foam in time. Or this is product which varies from item to item (low quality control)?

*Unfortunaly I am unable to recall what was the form when I bought the old bottle, because it was some years ago and meanwhile I used other brand.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess the old bottle has lost some of its carrier fluid (the clear liquid that separates on-top when the bottle is left to stand) and when shaken, the old bottle has a lot more of the lubricant compared to the newer bottle.

Either chuck the old bottle, or add a very small amount of something volatile like methylated spirits perhaps and use it up on a junker bike.

Only use the newer stuff on your good bikes.

Comment: I had a bottle of dry lube with a little left in the bottom, after 12 months or so in the car boot it was nearly solid. Added some iso prop alcohol and used it up on my kids bikes.

Comment: @mattnz Good idea.  I used some old dry lube to help ease two ethernet cables down some 10 metres of hose pipe that I wanted to protect outside.  Worked well for the purpose and I didn't have to waste the end of the bottle.